AmChart Pie Chart legend shouldn't be clickable but must allow hover
I am using AmChart's Pie Chart to display some categorical data. I also use a legend in order to allow users to see this chart's values when hovered over. When this legend's items are clicked it starts an animation and produces ticks over the chart. I want to disable this "tick" effect but still have the hover effect. I tried options like clickTarget: "none" which is to disable toggling but it also disables hovering effect.
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
let root = am5.Root.new(id);
root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

let chart = root.container.children.push(
  am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
    radius: am5.percent(90),
    innerRadius: am5.percent(50),
    layout: root.verticalLayout,
    height: am5.percent(90),
  })
);

let series = chart.series.push(
  am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
    name: "Series",
    valueField: "count",
    categoryField: "type",
    fillField: "color",
    legendLabelText: "{category}",
    legendValueText: "{value}",
  })
);

series.data.setAll(data);
series.labels.template.set("visible", false);
series.ticks.template.set("visible", false);
series.slices.template.set("strokeOpacity", 0);
series.slices.template.set("toggleKey", "none");
series.slices.template.set(
  "tooltipText",
  "[fontFamily: Mulish]{type}: {count} {valuePercent.formatNumber('#.0')}[/]"
);

let legend = chart.children.push(
  am5.Legend.new(root, {
    centerX: am5.percent(50),
    x: am5.percent(50),
    clickTarget: "none",
    layout: am5.GridLayout.new(root, {
      maxColumns: 2,
      fixedWidthGrid: true,
    }),
  })
);

legend.data.setAll(series.dataItems);
legend.valueLabels.template.set("forceHidden", true);
legend.labels.template.setAll({
  oversizedBehavior: "wrap",
  fontFamily: "Mulish",
});

return () => {
  root.dispose();
};

}, [data]);
